# Django Templates: how flexible are variables?

Tags: django, django-templates

I need to have a variable in a teplate that is basically a counter for a for-loop. The problem is: I need to manipulate it, depending on the for-element I am dealing with, I will have to reset the counter (an IF inside the for-loop).

Is this doable inside a Django template?

This is basically what I would like:

```
{% i = 0 %}
{% for l in list %}
    {% if i == 5 %}
        {% i = 0 %}
        Do Something
        <br>
    {% else %}
        {% i = i + 1 %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't with the builtin tags:

http://www.mail-archive.com/django-users@googlegroups.com/msg27399.html

The following snippets might be a good starting point:

- [Template counters](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1794/)
- [Access by index](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2740/)

**EDIT**: For the record, OP needed a conditional with divisibleby. See the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8494209/modulus-in-django-template) plus the comments in this answer.

Comment: @averageman It'd be easier if you can sort the iterable in the view prior to template rendering.

Comment: Well, it is already sorted but I need to do something in the HTML every 5 elements (something like a <br> for every 5 elements).

Comment: @averageman You could do a conditional with `forloop.counter 'module' 5`.

Comment: Can I do "counter modulo 5" in a Django template?

Comment: Sort of https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#divisibleby

Comment: I'm not familiar with the template tags but can I use them in an IF statement? Or just to output something to the HTML page?

Comment: Yes, you can. See the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8494209/modulus-in-django-template

Answer (score 1):

What you want is the `forloop.counter` variable that Django's template language provides.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#for

You would do something like:

```
{% for element in list %}
    {% if forloop.counter > 5 %}
        Do something
    {% else %}
        Do something else
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

If you want to do something cyclically, you're basically doing a modulo operator (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation), unfortunately, Django Template doesn't quite have this, but it does allow a 'divisible by' operator.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#divisibleby

So you'll add:

```
{% if {{ forloop.counter|divisibleby:"5" }} %}
    {{ whatever }}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: What do you mean by reset the counter? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I don't understand... you never do anything with `i` in your example.

Comment: @averageman Also, this should be done in the backend not in the template. Templates are preferably supposed to be dumb as a rock.