# How do I store a elements in a div so I can use them in a cycle in Django

Tags: django

I wan't to store this

```
<div class="container">
<div class="jumbotron">
<h1>Bootstrap Tutorial</h1>      
<p>Bootstrap is the most popular HTML, CSS, and JS framework for developing responsive, mobile-first projects on the web.</p>
</div>
<p>This is some text.</p>      
<p>This is another text.</p>      
</div>
```

in a div so I can use it in Django "cycle"

```
{% cycle "" "" "" "variable here" "" "" "" "</div><div class='row'>"%}
```

The django docs mention it can be done,but does not demonstrate how. I tried storing them in an include but that did not work either. How Could this be done?

Comment: What is the output you want from this? This doesn't look like typical usage of `cycle`. You can use the template tag `include` to reuse template snippets, if that's what you are looking for. https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#include

Comment: @HåkenLid thanks for the response sorry if I dont fully understand the correct usage. I'm going off of a tutorial and drawing my own conclusions. I wanted to insert a div after every four div posts, for something banner ads. Instead of putting includes over and over again. Trying to keep things dry

Comment: Maybe you can use this approach? http://stackoverflow.com/a/8494425/1977847