# ListView with alternate background image

Tags: django

This code doesn't work! I want to show an red image and then a blue image. If I have 5 object the the list should be: Red Blue Red Blue Red.

I want to do this with 2 colours. I tried the following code:

```
 {% extends './base.html' %}
 {% block content %}
 {% for object in object_list %}

 {% if forloop.counter0 % 2 ==0 }

 <img src="img/red.jpg">
 <p> {{object.title}} </p>

 {% else %}
 <img src="img/blue.jpg">
 <p> {{object.title}} </p>


 {% endif %}


{% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Modulus % in Django template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8494209/modulus-in-django-template)

Comment: The *Modulus % in Django template* question is similar, but the best answer for Davide's case is to use the cycle tag (currently 10 upvotes), not the accepted answer to use divisibleby (currently 141 upvotes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `%` in templates. Django has a [`divisibleby`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#divisibleby) filter you could use.

However, it would be better to use the [`cycle`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#cycle) tag:

```
{% for object in object_list %}
    <img src="{% cycle 'image/red.jpg' 'image/blue.jpg' %}">
    <p>{{object.title}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Django templates don't have modulus %, they use `divisibleby:2`

So your code would be this instead:

```
{% if forloop.counter0|divisibleby:2 %}
```