# How do I combine two arrays in for loop fashion so the 3 items of one list appear then 1 item of the other list appears, in python (django)

Tags: python, django, social-networking

I'm building a social media site with events and posts and I want the user feed to have new events advertised every 4 posts. So basically the feed would look like:

Post 1, Post 2, Post 3, Event 1, Post 4, Post 5, Post 6, Event 2, ...

Do I do this in the template or view? And how do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

In your view, you can do the following:

```
def every_nth(iter1, iter2, n):
    count = 1
    while True:
        if count % n == 0:
            element_iter_2 = next(iter2, None)
            if element_iter_2: yield element_iter_2
        else:
            element_iter_1 = next(iter1, None)
            if element_iter_1: yield element_iter_1
        count += 1
        if not (element_iter_1 or element_iter_2):
            return

posts = ['p1', 'p2', 'p3', 'p4', 'p5', 'p6']  # Assuming you have iterables that contain posts
events = ['e1', 'e2', 'e3', 'e4']  # ... and events

iter_posts = iter(posts)
iter_events = iter(events)
combine = list(every_nth(iter_posts, iter_events, 4))

# combine = ['p1', 'p2', 'p3', 'e1', 'p4', 'p5', 'p6', 'e2']
```

Comment: I am not a native english speaker. Is this something good or bad XD?

Comment: Oh, thank you so much, I am glad that you said so :-)

Comment: Something like this indeed. But what will happen if there are no events but 10 posts? :-)

Comment: This is a valid point. You will get the first three posts and thats it. But why would you want to call this method with emtpy events? :-)

Comment: It could be that there are more than 3x the amount of posts than events and then you have the same issue ;-)

Comment: I updated my solution to bring it to the same level as yours.

Comment: Nice, well done, I added a solution as well based on some inspiration from yours ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Basic idea from [Yves Hary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63595787/2240807) but with the guarantee that every item will be displayed:

```
from itertools import chain, zip_longest

# From python itertools cookbook: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html
def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)

events = ['e1', 'e2', 'e3', 'e4']
posts = ['p1', 'p2', 'p3', 'p4', 'p5', 'p6']

combined = [
    *chain(
        *chain(
            *zip_longest(
                grouper(posts, 3),
                grouper(events, 1),
                fillvalue=[],
            )
        )
    )
]
```

combined = `['p1', 'p2', 'p3', 'e1', 'p4', 'p5', 'p6', 'e2', 'e3', 'e4']`

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do that in the template you can use the for counter and add a filter in the template. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8494209/modulus-in-django-template/8494425) post should be helpful

the other way is to do in the view function. The code there is similar to the one you need for the template. Simply iterate over the posts, and check if the index divides by four exactly and if yes push an event into the list.