# Using "%" as a modulo operator in Django template

Tags: django, django-templates

I have color swatches being displayed under some ecommerce items in a Django 3.6 template.  I would like to add a line break after every 5 swatches.  To implement this I used this HTML.

```
{% if forloop.counter % 5 == 0 %}
  <br>
{% endif %}
```

but when I render the page I get this error.

```
Could not parse the remainder: '%' from '%'
```

How can I use this operator inside of a template?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Modulus % in Django template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8494209/modulus-in-django-template)

Comment: It does.  Thank you!

Comment: Or, `x_mod_n = x - ( x//n)*n`